# Google Contacts on IP phones via asterisk PBX

Tags: exchange, cisco, asterisk

I've skimmed google on this but haven't found anything too useful.

Is there a way to use Google Contacts with a HardPhone supported by Asterisk PBX?

Google contacts is exposed thru a MSExchange server

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I saw that you tagged Cisco in our question, so I am guessing you are using Cisco phones, I have only used Cisco phones with Asterisk, so that is all I will be able to cover in my answer.

The first thing you will need to do is add a directory entry to your SIPDefault.cnf file (inside the TFTP directory your phone points to. Here is the line you need to add:

```
directory_url: "http://yourWebsiteOrIp/directory.xml";
```

The url must be a web server that is accessible to the phone, not the server. That line can go anywhere in the SIPDefault.cnf file

The file on the server should follow this format:

```
<CiscoIPPhoneDirectory>       

   <Title>Directory name (will appear in menu)</Title>
   <Prompt>Select a person to call</Prompt>                    

   <DirectoryEntry>                                              
     <Name>My Phone</Name>         
     <Telephone>101</Telephone>
   </DirectoryEntry>                                      

</CiscoIPPhoneDirectory>
```

Unfortunately I am not all that experienced with exchange or gmail. What I gan tell you is that you will need to create a cron job that will run a program every x amount of time that will generate this XML file and put it on the server. Every time the phone accesses the directory it will download the XML file.

EDIT: Here is a link that provides a lot of useful information, including a section on creating the XML file with PHP: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Cisco+79XX+XML+Services

Hope that helps some!

Comment: cool, now all thats left is google contacts to xml.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend on the hardphone in question.  Polycom phones will pick up files of a certain name (00000000-directory.xml, I think) from the ftp/tftp/http server that they get their config from.  You could conceivably snag the contacts and periodically regenerate that file. [This manual](http://www.polycom.com/global/documents/support/setup_maintenance/products/voice/spip_ssip_Admin_Guide_SIP_3_1.pdf) has details; see page 4-10 (p64 in the pdf) for details on the 'Local Contact Directory File Format'.  Oh, looks like there's a new feature since I last looked: Corporate Directory (p4-34/p88) that is a way to point the phone directly at an LDAP server.

Comment: so there's directory listings are seperate from asterisk and vendor specific?

Comment: Yes, because they're accessed directly from the phone, not through asterisk.  Asterisk also has a 'dial the first 4 letters of the last name of the person you wish to reach'-style directory suitable for being an option from an auto-attendant, but I didn't think that was what you were asking about.

Comment: that's pretty cool, does asterisk use a similar xml directory for that?

Comment: I think asterisk's only real directory is the users.conf one, which is more like a .ini file than like xml.

Answer (score 2):

1. Log into Google Contacts and Export your contacts. There's a link in the top-right to do this, and will offer a choice of three formats: Google CSV, Outlook CSV, or vCard. Choose vCard.
2. When the "Downloads" box pops up with contacts.vcf, right-click and choose "Copy Download Link." It should look something like this:

   http //mail.google.com/mail/contacts/data/export?exportType=GROUP&groupToExport=%5EMine&out=VCARD
3. Go install the [vcardcmxml script](http://vostrom.com/vcardcmxml/).
4. Feed the output of your Google contacts export to the vcardcmxml script.
5. Use cron to lather, rinse, repeat for updates to the Contacts list as frequently as necessary.

Comment: that sounds like the solution

Answer (score 1):

All VoIP phones that support directory XML can be made to work with arbitrary data. You just have to program that functionality. You can provide the XML data from a database on the fly via some scripting engine running on the server, or just a static XML file generated at some time. Nothing out of the box I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks, guess I'm going to have to roll my own on this one